# How to correlate properly a moving sample in 2 images of different size?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am currently recording on a single camera the images, one aside of the other one, of the same sample out of a microscope.

I have 2 issues with that, and I figured out that in post procesing with Matlab I could arrange these questions.

-First, the 2 images on the camera are supposed to have the same pixel size, or one is just a litle bigger than the other one, probably because of optical pathways. What is the adapted Matlab function or way to correlate the two images so they will have exactly the same pixel size in X and Y ?

[Two images on same camera , one bigger or smaller compared to the other one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlvXT.png)

-Secondly, my sample is moving a litle during the recording ( while still staying in my field of view of course ). To make my analysis easier, it would be suitable that I could correct the images so the sample remain at the same place as in the first image, to perform calculations on it easier. What would be the adapted Matlab function or way to correct this movement in the image ?

[Sample moving in the image on the camera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Enx02.png)

Sorry for the poor quality of my drawings !

Thank you very much for your advices and help.

Answer (score 0):

First zero-pad the images to a sufficient degree, to get them both to double the size of the bigger one.

```
size_padding = max(size(fig1),size(fig2));
fig1_pad = padarray(fig1,size_padding-size(fig1),'post');
fig2_pad = padarray(fig2,size_padding-size(fig2),'post');
```

Assuming the sample is the only feature present in the images, the best way to proceed would be to use the `xcorr2()` function and find the lag corresponding to the maximum correlation, to get the space shift between the two images:

```
xc = xcorr2(fig1_pad,fig2_pad);
[max_cc, imax] = max(abs(xc(:)));
[ypeak, xpeak] = ind2sub(size(xc),imax(1));
corr_offset = [ (ypeak-size(fig2_pad,1)) (xpeak-size(fig2_pad,2)) ];
```

You then use `circshift()` to shift one of the images using the lag you obtained in the last step.

```
fig2_shift = circshift(fig2_pad,corr_offset);
```

You now have two images of the same size, where hopefully the sample is in the same position. If you want to remove the padding zeroes, crop the images to your liking with respect to the center using `imcrop()`.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your help. This is pretty much what I imagined, while not really being able to put it off. I am going to try it ASAP ;)